# Rails 5 validation on update fires on create too

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using factory bot gem to build my factory objects for rspec test. And I have a validation like this in my model :

```
validates :reason_for_change, presence: true, on: :update
```

The spec test fails because the object itself cannot be created :

```
Failure/Error: let(:user) { create(:super_user) }

     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Profile reason for change can't be blank
```

I have also tried this:

```
validates :reason_for_change, presence: true, unless: :new_record?
```

Same error. This as well :

```
validates :reason_for_change, presence: true, if: :my_custom_method

def my_custom_method
  !new_record?
end
```

Same result. However when I used the last validation and put a breakpoint inside my custom method like this :

```
def my_custom_method
  binding.pry
end
```

And was manually first checking is this a `new_record?`, whenever it would evaluate to true, I would return false (manually typing). And for every false evaluated, I'd return true (manually typing).

In this case all tests pass. What is going on here? I am using rails `5.0.1`

**Update 1:**

Here is my super user factory :

```
factory :super_user do
    transient do
      email { nil }
    end
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name  { Faker::Name.last_name }
    gender { 'male' }
    age { Random.rand(18..40) }
    ethnicity { '' }
    avatar { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec/files/1.png')) }
  end
```

**Also I don't think I should modify factory, just to make this work. This should work.**

Comment: @spickermann I just updated

Comment: I am confused. The factory is for a `SuperUser`, but the error message says: _Profile_ reason for change can't be blank. Are a profile and a super user the same thing?

Comment: yes, sorry that this is confusing @spickermann

Comment: @Remember_me, please check the logs. I believe, you will see there something like this:
```INSERT INTO super_users () VALUES(...);
UPDATE super_users SET filed = val
```
If so - please check another callbacks that may be run when record is saved. My guess is that you have another callback that updates same record in, for example, after_save callback.

Comment: Forgot to mention - you should disable that validation first before trying my suggestion.

Comment: you're right @intale can you post an answer. I ll accept. The update does update the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A copy-paste of my comment:
Please check the logs. I believe, you will see there something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO super_users () VALUES(...) 
UPDATE super_users SET filed = val
```

If so - please check another callbacks that may be run when record is saved. My guess is that you have another callback that updates same record in, for example, after_save callback.
You should disable that validation first before trying my suggestion.